# How to test a version of an app from a dedicated branch on a remote server?

Tags: git, merge, git-branch, git-remote, git-checkout

Locally I have checked out a new branch, changed code of my app, committed these changes into that new dedicated branch. Now I would like to test this version of my app on a server. How may I do it?

Usually my workflow is as follows. Locally I have two branches: `dev` and `master`. I write code in a `dev` branch. When I’m ready to upload code to a remote server I merge `dev` into `master` and push all to a remote repo.

So locally I do this:

```
$ git branch
 * dev
   master
$ git add --all
$ git commit -m “Ready to push on server”
$ git checkout master
$ git merge dev
$ git push –u origin --all
```

Then on a remote server, I do this:

```
$ git fetch --all
$ sudo git reset --hard origin/master
$ npm start
```

But now, as I said earlier, I have created a new branch `react-server-render`. I have re-coded my app so that it uses server-side React rendering. I would like to test only this branch on a server. I wouldn't like to merge `react-server-render` into `master` to test the code. I would like to test it as a `react-server-render` branch and if there are any issues I'd like to switch back to `master` again. How can I do it with Git?

Comment: I work with enterprise Java (WARs running on Tomcat), and we consider Git branches and testing things to be two largely decoupled phenomena.  Why can't you just test your test branch either locally or on the server and then decide whether or not you want to keep it?

Answer (score 1):

I would say locally do:

```
git push -u origin react-server-render
```

And on the remote:

```
git fetch
git co react-server-render
npm start
```

And if you want to go back to the old code on the remote:

```
git co master
npm start
```